# Broken control panel glass on propane range

Tags: kitchens, appliances

The glass covering the control panel on our Whirlpool propane range shattered after I don’t a pot on it. Whirlpool says I need to replace entire control panel ($949.00). Can I just remove the glass and get a piece of glass cut to cover it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the damage, added to your question, would really help.

Comment: Model # of the range?

Comment: Check around with some local appliance repair shops. They may have spare parts around that were scavenged from "wrecked" appliances. In my experience, the smaller the shop, the better the luck finding such things.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, any new piece of glass would likely not be an appropriate replacement.  Many different kinds of glass exist, and only some of these types of glass are suitable in a high heat environment.

The reasons why a kind of glass is not suitable depends on the glass formulation.  Some glass has a lower temperature of deformation, while others expand or have poor heat shock properties (they fracture upon spot heating easily).  In addition, many types of glass are treated after manufacture to improve their properties (like tempering, which greatly increases the impact resistance).

For example, borosilicate glass (Pyrex) does well in some cooking scenarios, while your typical sheet glass (or even stained glass) would shatter nearly immediately.  Odds are sourcing an equivalent glass will be problematic.

That said, the glass is probably not the reason for the expense.  Oven manufacturers have simplified their replacement parts lists by shipping assemblies, and high temperature tolerating control panels are expensive due to their relative lack of reuse (so low production runs) and relatively high use of non-scalable manufacturing methods (due to the heat handling requirements).

It's a shame, and I still am a bit sore over discarding a very nice induction stove over some simple damage to 1/3 of a display that couldn't be purchased independently of the 3 part assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Can you post a photo of it? If it's an LCD control panel, then they may be correct because the glass is part of the assembly. If it's just a piece of glass over something else, you MIGHT be able to replace it, but you would need (most likely) for it to be tempered glass and most glass shops will not do that (I've tried).

Comment: If you can find a shop that cuts tempered glass, they can work this item.  Cutting tempered glass really isn't cutting tempered glass.  It is cutting non-tempered glass (or glass that was tempered, but then relaxed in a glass oven) and then re-tempering it (which involves heating it, and then forced air cooling the surface).  Any attempt to cut tempered glass releases the pressure within the surface, which sends a shock wave through the glass, shattering it.  Odds are that this person knows if he has tempered glass just by how it broke.  A few big pieces is not tempered.  Glass nuggets is.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago , I replaced the glass control panel on a Kitchen Aide; $ 1000 + labor. Never did work right ,ended up getting a new stove with no glass panel . It would have been cheaper to replace the stove in the first place.